# How to read informations from a database on xcode?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, database, xcode

for my Xcode project I need to read informations from a sql database.
My database is composed of 2 columns : the first one contains the year, the other one the price. 
What I want is to take the information of the second one from the information of the first one. 
For example if I wrote 1990 on my text field then my variable will be equal to the price for 1990.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: did u check the answer

Answer (score 0):

**check this**

```
- (NSArray*) findByPrice:(NSString*)year
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
                NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM  yourDatabaseName"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *year1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                NSString *price = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                        (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                if ([year1 isEqualToString: year]) {
                    [resultArray addObject:year1];
                    [resultArray addObject:price];
                    NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
                }
            }

            NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
            return resultArray;
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);

    }
    return nil;
}
```

and show the resultant array of object index value in ur resultant label.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a database does not consist of "columns". Your business "table" should be composed of 2 columns.

Secondly, it s not directly Xcode related question. Xcode is an ide, not an application development platform, language or a library. Do you code in Swift or Objective C ? Be more clear about your question.

By the way question does not related to Swift or Objective C too. What your need is to learn basic sql select command at first.

Please take a look at how to implement a select query. You can start from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm)